# Gem Load Error about whois command and removed cache

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have an awesome trouble with Gem.  After executing this command:

```
rm -f /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/*
```

I can not do any thing.  If I try for instance: **gem cleanup** I get this kind of answer:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gemwhois-0.1/lib/gemwhois.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems/commands/whois (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gemwhois-0.1/lib/gemwhois.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gemwhois-0.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb:2:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gemwhois-0.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1113:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1113:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1105:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:235:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:235:in `load_full_rubygems_library'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:334:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/bin/gem:12:in `<main>'
```

It's the same for **gem -v**, of just **gem** command...

I'm working of Snow Leopard.  What should the best solution about you?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!  now it's solved AHAHAH~

My solution was:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
sudo rm -r gemwhois-0.*
```

Ruby is **cool**.  Have fun.